# Why my thread doesn't stop after function finished?

Tags: python, multithreading, packet-sniffers

So I wrote this script, which counts income packets on certain port, and in case if there are to many packets script has to do something. On the first received packet is has to start timer, and if timer reaches 60 sec, packet count should start from 0 again. It works, but only for first timer call, in any case, if script has to start timer again I get the error:

```
raise RuntimeError("threads can only be started once")
RuntimeError: threads can only be started once"`
```

It's clear, that this thread still running, but i don't understand why. I mean, in case if timer reaches 60 secs, timer loop is finished, and function should be finished too, so i can use timer again? Clearly i don't understand something here, can you guys explain it? Thanks for answers
My code:

```py
from scapy.all import *
from threading import Thread
import time
global count
count = 0

def timer():
    global count
    i = 0
    while i < 60:
        if count > 0:
            time.sleep(1)
            i = i + 1
            print(str(count))
        else:
            print("count is 0, timer turning off...")
            break
    else:
        count = 0
        print("60 seconds, timer is off")

background_thread = Thread(target=timer)

def pkt_callback(pkt):
    global count
    packet_limit = 10

    if pkt.haslayer(UDP) and pkt.getlayer(UDP).dport == 5160 and pkt.haslayer(Raw):
        raw = pkt.getlayer(Raw).load
        s = str(raw)

        if 'REGISTER' in s:
            count += 1
            print(count)

        if count == 1:
            if background_thread.is_alive() is False:
                background_thread.start()
                print("Register packet detected, timer is on")

        if count >= packet_limit:
            print("PACKETLIMIT reached, do smth")
            count = 0

        sniff(iface='ens160', filter="", prn=pkt_callback)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to use the return function not break, and either way you have only used it once, also you can change your code a bit, try this:

```
def timer():
       global count
       i = 0
       while i < 60:
           if count != 0:
                time.sleep(1)
                i += 1
                print(str(count))
           else:
                return "count is 0, timer turning off..."
       else:
           count = 0
           return "60 seconds, timer is off"
```

Comment: Thanks for tip, but even with ur code i have same error, when it comes to second timer

Comment: can you take a screenshot to show what's happening with the code

Comment: Also, something which i do it put ``print('Working')`` to see whether something is working or not

Comment: https://photos.app.goo.gl/z7Tjakj9T1gyuJFu6
digits are numbers of received packets

Comment: Sorry, changed packet_limit to 3, so you can see full run, should have done it by the start. https://photos.google.com/share/AF1QipOHdncyjELIZklgbU5sLG9uGUpnvogZHwl1FrULcSwnNdTPaVeVZ6s7hhNRu4CS0g/photo/AF1QipMc3Eqv0FMZTJ21h_s_DA9U4wy2Ah7-ISYvHgRo?key=ckUxNDdrdjFEREo2QnM4N2t5V3Y4a1B0S1ctTlJ3

Comment: is this the entire code that you have used?

Comment: yeah, i edited code with return, just like u said. Also i added print before both returns, so i can see what's happening

Comment: Ok, so reading it side by side, your code says ``if count > 0:``, but then in the ``if 'REGISTER' in s:`` it adds 1 to count so count can never be zero, so its going to continue, that might be the problem?